# Minimum spanning trees

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose we have a connected, undirected graph $G=(V,E)$, with a weight function $w\colon E\to R$ and let $T$ be a minimum spanning tree.  Now assume that we remove a particular edge $e$.  The exercise is to find a minimum spanning tree to the new graph.

I've thought of an algorithm:  Look at the cut determined by $T$ and $e$, and then replace $e$ by the minimal weighted edge crossing that cut (if such an edge exists).  But I don't know how to prove this works.  Help?

Comment: Clearly, if $e$ is not in $T$, then $T$ is a minimal spanning tree of $G-e$. Also, if $e$ is a cut-edge of $G$, then $G-e$ is not connected, hence no spanning tree exists.

Comment: I agree. So the problem is reduced to the situation where e is in T, and it isn't a cut edge

Comment: I don't know what is meant by "the cut determined by $T$ and $e$."

Comment: I assume e is in T.  So if I remove e from T, then two connected components are left, and they form a cut for the graph (i.e a partition of V into two subsets).  That's what I meant in "the cut determined by T and e".